# Enumerate slice entries

Tags: json, go

If I have this output

```
Stuff {
    "Items": [
            {
                "title": "test1",
                "id": "1",
            },
            {
                "title": "test",
                "id": "2",
            },
        ],
        "total": 19
    },
}
```

But want this instead:

```
stuff {
    "Items": [
        1:{
            "title": "test1",
            "id": "1",
        },
        2:{
            "title": "test",
            "id": "2",
        },
    ],
    "total": 19
    },
}
```

Currently, my structs are build like this:

```
Stuff struct {
    Items           []Items         `json:"items"`
    Total           int             `json:"total"`
} `json:"stuff"`


type Items struct {
    Title             string        `json:"title"`
    ID                string        `json:"id"`
}
```

I initiate a slice by:

```
stuff := make([]Items, 10)    // Lets say I have 10 entries
```

And append by:

```
Stuff.Items = stuff
Stuff.Total = len(Stuff.Items)
```

Now I am unsure on how to numerate that. So for every item entries, there should be a number, starting from 1 - 10 (In this example)

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON. Keys can only be strings. `encoding/json` supports parsing and generating valid JSON.

Comment: So, if i want it to be "1":{}, "2"{}, and so on. How do i do that?

Comment: The simpplest is to convert it to a map, then marshal the map. What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

Given your `Stuff` and `Items` type declarations, here's a simple data structure and its JSON dump:

```
s := Stuff{Items: []Items{Items{"test1", "1"}, Items{"test2", "2"}}, Total: 10}
j, err := json.MarshalIndent(s, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(j))
```

JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "test1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "test2",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ],
  "total": 10
}
```

To see what you want instead, there's no magic `json` package call to do that. You'll have to create a new data structure that reflects the structure of your desired output.

In this case a simple map will do:

```
m := make(map[string]Items)
for _, item := range s.Items {
    m[item.ID] = item
}
```

And now if you JSON-dump this map, you get:

```
{
  "1": {
    "title": "test1",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "2": {
    "title": "test2",
    "id": "2"
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not wrapping it with `Stuff` now, because `Stuff` has different fields. Go is *statically typed*, and each struct can only contain the fields you declared it to have.